# formating Double values in I/O files in java...

Tags: java

Please how do i format the value of the updatedsalary in this program to 2 decimal places???

```
     package elapsedTime;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Salary {

public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException {
    String firstname,lastname;
    double currentSalary, PayIncrease;
    double updatedsalary;
Scanner infile=new Scanner(new FileReader("Ch3_Ex7Data.txt"));
PrintWriter Outfile=new PrintWriter("Outdata.dat");
    firstname=infile.next();
    lastname=infile.next();
    currentSalary=infile.nextDouble();
    PayIncrease=infile.nextDouble();
    updatedsalary=((PayIncrease*currentSalary)/100)+currentSalary;
Outfile.printf("FIRSTNAME:"+firstname+"\n"+"LASTNAME:"+lastname+"\n"+"UPDATEDSALARY:"+updatedsalary+"\n"+"\n");
firstname=infile.next();
lastname=infile.next();
currentSalary=infile.nextDouble();
PayIncrease=infile.nextDouble();
updatedsalary=((PayIncrease*currentSalary)/100)+currentSalary;
Outfile.printf("FIRSTNAME:"+firstname+"\n"+"LASTNAME:"+lastname+"\n"+"UPDATEDSALARY:"+updatedsalary+"\n"+"\n");
firstname=infile.next();
lastname=infile.next();
currentSalary=infile.nextDouble();
PayIncrease=infile.nextDouble();
updatedsalary=((PayIncrease*currentSalary)/100)+currentSalary;
Outfile.printf("FIRSTNAME:"+firstname+"\n"+"LASTNAME:"+lastname+"\n"+"UPDATEDSALARY:"+updatedsalary+"\n"+"\n");
infile.close();
Outfile.close();
}
```

}
 i am mainly confused as to where to use the format specifiers in the Outfile.printf statement..

Comment: Indent your code. And only post the relevant parts. And here's a hint: This question has been answered dozens of times already (here on SO).

Comment: Its generally a bad idea to use doubles for displaying/manipulating currency, but if you still want to go down that road, look at the DecimalFormat class.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [Decimal Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).
You would do something like

```
double d = 2.34568;
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
Outfile.printf(f.format(d));
```

Comment: thanks guys... i am new to STACKOVERFLOW.. kinda had little issues posting the code... will surely indent my code next time... by the way, i formatted it successfully using the %.2f format specifier... thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line of code to print the salary to 2 decimal places:

```
Outfile.printf("FIRSTNAME:"+firstname+"\n"+"LASTNAME:"+lastname+"\n"+"UPDATEDSALARY:%.2f\n"+"\n", updatedsalary);
```